# How to select an id bigger then

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a news system for a website. I used the news system from this tutorial: http://pixelcode.co.uk/tutorials/php/mysql-news-system/

So to display the news I use this line of code:

```
if(!$_GET['id'])
        {   
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC");
            while($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
                    echo '<div id="nieuws">';
                    echo '<a href="?id='.$output['id'].'" id="link">';                      
                    echo '<h1>'.$output['title'].'</h1>';
                    echo '<span id="date">'.date('d-m-y', $output['date']).'</span><br / >';
                    echo $output['shortnews'].'<br / >';
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '</div>';      
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $id = $_GET['id']; 
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='$id'");
            $output = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);                
    ?>      
            <form method="post" action="?id=<? echo $output['id']; ?>"> 

            <h1><? echo $output['title']; ?></h1>
            <? echo '<span id="date">'.date('d-m-y', $output['date']).'</span><br / >' ?>
            <? echo $output['news']; ?>
            </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

I can do: `if(!$_GET['id'] = 6)` but I can't do this: `if(!$_GET['id'] > 6)`. What's the problem? Or is there another code for bigger then an id?

Thanks for replying, MARCH

Comment: The ! doesnt work with the bigger than. If you want to trigger at bigger than remove the ! If a smaller then usw < the ! is not needed

Comment: That tutorial is terribly insecure and outdated. You also are varying between short tags and non; you will be better using the longer opening `<?php` so you dont have to reconfigure PHP instances in the future if you move this to other servers/php versions.

Comment: This is the perfect moment for you to learn about SQL injection attacks. The code you've just written basically hands control of your website on a silver platter to anyone with even a basic understanding of hacking.

Comment: Do _not_ use the deprecated `mysql_*` interface; instead move to `mysqli_*`.

Answer (score 4):

[Operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php): `!` binds tighter than `==`, so you're effectively doing

```
(not($_GET) == 6)
```

That's why there's `!=` for inequality tests.

If you'd used proper bracketing, e.g

```
(!($_GET['id'] == 6))
```

then you'd be doing

```
not(id == 6)
```

and get your expected results, because that's logically/functionally equivalent to `id != 6`

And note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and are using an obsolete/deprecated DB interface.

Comment: Hi, my english is not so good and I can't coclude what code I need to use. Could you please only write down the code for bigger than id 6? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset()`:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) ...
```

Or, what I like to do:

```
// Get all possible arguments:
$id  = @$_GET['id'];   // The @ prevents an error message
$foo = @$_GET['foo'];  // foo means ...  (explain the args)
...
// Later, as needed:
if (isset($id)) ...
```